# Breaker tripping I believe jumper discovered

Tags: electrical

[image]So when using my space heaters on opposite ends of my house I keep tripping my breaker (that seems to control my lights and a few receptacles) my question is what is the second wire running from behind the breaker to the main rails purpose and would removing and changing the breaker cause me problems? I know I have disconnected wires I've done some deleting and repurposing. My concern as of now is if removing the jumper and replacing the 15a with a 20 will fix my problem or cause more issues [image]

Comment: What jumper? Can you draw an arrow on the picture or tell us what breaker it connects to (“fourth from the top on the left” or similar)?

Comment: You can't just replace a 15 amp breaker with a 20 amp breaker. The wire needs to be a certain thickness (12 gauge) for 20 amp lines; 15 amp lines are typically 14 gauge. Two space heaters will normally push a single 20 amp/12 gauge line to its max. Two space heaters on a 20 amp/14 gauge line can start a fire.

Comment: I added another photo if it helps my confusion with the second wire that's connected behind the breaker which is routed behind the breaker

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be referring to the gfci grounded conductor (white wire with stranded guts). A gfci breaks both grounded and 'hot' wires when tripped, (it's circuitry might use the ground also) so the grounded conductor (white) is run through the breaker as well as the black.

The gfci is there to protect from accidental electrocution in wet areas, like kitchen, garage, outside, and bath. For those areas, the wiring is probably 12 gauge and 20 amps. For the kitchen, NEC code requires it. This is because kitchen appliances are mostly space heater level devices in amperage draw.

If you replace the breaker, it will need to be a gfci breaker rated the amperage needed to protect the branch circuit (15 amp for 14 awg, 20 amp for 12 awg (copper)).

15 amp breakers will allow for a continuous 12 amp draw (roughly 1200 watts), 20 amp breakers allow 16 amps continuous. Generally, they will trip around an amp or so above rated (i.e 16 amps for a 15 amp breaker), or right around the rated level.

Refer to the appropriate sections of the NEC code for allowable amperages and required wiring methods.

Not a good idea, or legal, to run small wires on large breakers. (The wires might start behaving like space heaters in the walls...very bad). If you are tripping the breaker from overload, (not ground-fault) it means you are drawing more amps than the rated level of the breaker for too long. (Heater runs for a few minutes before tripping the breaker)

Hope this helps. There are some really sharp electrician types on this site that can give better responses and cite code references better than I can.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Also I wiggled the stranded white wire to see if it's securely connected and it arced I was going to just secure the connection but with you saying it's a ground, I didn't Believe grounds were supposed to have power? I'm

Comment: That's what you get when you use the toxic term "grounded conductor" when you mean neutral LOL.  NEC is targeted at professionals.  Just because NEC lawyers think it's a good term to communicate with educators and master electricians, does NOT make it a good term for us to communicate with novices.

Comment: The 'Grounded' (neutral) conductor is anything but 'neutral' (Grounded makes sense when used in context). A current carrying, insulated conductor that returns amperage to the main panel and transformer. The 'Grounding' conductor (green or bare) is non-current carrying and is used to ensure the 'neutral' doesn't use people to get back to the transformer. It is a good point that if you are working with wiring you need to be familiar with NEC and local codes and It would be a good idea to speak with the local jurisdiction about necessary inspections and permits before making any changes.